# How to return the index of vector after sorting

Tags: matlab, sorting, vector

I must sort a vector in descending order. I want to get the index of the vector after sorting. I assume that I have a vector `A=[7 6 5]` that is indexed from `[1 2 3].` The vector A is sorted as `[5 6 7]` then the sorting index of vector A will be change `[3 2 1].` In which 3 is index of 5 goes to first, 2 is index of 6...These index is arranged based on the value of A after sorting. How to do it in Matlab. For example

```
A=[7 6 5]
Index_A=[1 2 3]
%Sort A
A_sort=[5 6 7]
Index_sort=[3 2 1]
```

Currently, I used the function

```
A_sort=sortrows(A')'
```

But I cannot achieve the index of vector after sorting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's easy: use the second output of [`sort`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html):

```
[A_sort, Index_sort] = sort(A);
```

Comment: @user8430 this is quite a common feature for Matlab functions e.g. `min`, `max`, `unique`, `ismember` etc have similar behaviour

Comment: Yes. I just think that vector is describe as row. Hence, I just find solution as sortrows function. It is very good point about sort function